# How do I put input fields into 2 columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a form which currently is all in one column, I would like it to be split into 2 columns.

I have tried adding div classes, but the form is still only one column, I do not want to do any changes to the current form itself. I would just like to be able to split it into 2 columns.

I would also not like the current CSS effects that I have on the fields to change..

```css
$yellow:#f5ba1a;
$black:#000000;
$grey:#cccccc;

   .form-style-1{
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 0.em;
width: 40em;
padding: 1em;
border: 1px solid #cbc9c9;
overflow:auto;
resize:both;

   }

   .form-style-1 fieldset{
       border-radius:none;

   background-color:#ebebeb;

   padding:5px;

    border:1px solid #cbc9c9;

  width:450px;

   margin:auto;
   box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31);
       -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.31);

   }



            .form__field {
                display: block;
}
[class*="--checkbox"] {
                display: inline-block;
}
[data-conditional] {
                display: none;
}
#flight:checked ~ [data-conditional*="flight"] {
                display: block;
}
#hotel:checked ~ [data-conditional*="hotel"] {
                display: block;
}
#transfer:checked ~ [data-conditional*="travel"] {
                display: block;
}

input[type="text"]
{
 display:block;
 width: 50%;
      padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
      height: 25px;
    
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
}

input[type="date"]
{
    display:block;
  width: 50%;
      padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
      height: 25px;
       
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
     background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
}

textarea {
    display:block;
     width: 50%;
      padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
      height: 25px;
     
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
}

select {
    display:block;
     width: 50%;
      padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
      height: 35px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
}

input[type="time"]
{
    display:block;
  width: 50%;
      padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
      height: 25px;

      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
     background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
  border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a.button {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 25px 0px 20px;
  margin: 10px 8px 20px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 50px; height: 27px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #3a57af;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75);
  box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58,87,175,.75);
  transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

a.button:hover {
  top: 3px;
  background-color:#2e458b;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;

}

p {

    color:black;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-1">
 <h1>Travel Registration Form</h1>
 <form action="" method="POST">
  <input name="orgid" type="hidden" value="00D8E000000DW9t" /> <input name="retURL" type="hidden" value="http://" />
  <fieldset>
  
   <h3>
    Select Travel</h3>
   <input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" data-input="00N8E000002AjRq" id="flight" type="checkbox" />
   <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="flight"> <span class="form__label">Flight</span> 
   </label> 
   <input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" id="hotel" type="checkbox" /> 
   <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="hotel"> <span class="form__label">Hotel</span> </label>
   
   <input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" id="transfer" type="checkbox" /> 
   <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="transfer"> <span class="form__label">Transfer </span> 
   </label>
   
   <!--Above is the checkboxes code -->
   
   
   <p class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel">
    <span class="form__input">Traveler's Information </span></p>
    
    
    
   <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="name"><span class="form__label">Traveler Name </span><input class="form__input" id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" /> </label><br>
   
   <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="email">Email<input class="form__input" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email"  size="20" type="text" /></label><br /> 
   
   <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="phone">Phone<input class="form__input" id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /></label><br />
   
   <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="subject">Subject<input class="form__input" id="subject" maxlength="80" name="subject" size="20" type="text" /></label><br />
   
   <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="description">Description<textarea class="form__input" name="description"></textarea></label><br />
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by `two columns`.

Comment: @10101010 select one of the checkbox to see the actual form

Comment: Yup I see the form. What is to be done there?

Comment: @10101010 form divided into 2 columns

Comment: @10101010 need to divide the input fields into 2 columns inside the form

Comment: @Prihan, you can take 2 div and put your code into that according to your design. Left side data into left div and right side data into the right div. also write 'float:left; position:relative' into that div's CSS if there is a need.

Comment: Surely you could just wrap your labels and inputs in divs and then align them as you would with you divs?

Comment: @jakelovelock how can i do that i get an error msg saying duplicate attribute class tag. can you do me a small snippet and show . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made use of CSS grid to get the two columns.

```css
$yellow: #f5ba1a;
      $black: #000000;
      $grey: #cccccc;

      .form-style-1 {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 0em;
        width: 40em;
        padding: 1em;
        border: 1px solid #cbc9c9;
        overflow: auto;
        resize: both;
      }

      .form-style-1 fieldset {
        border-radius: none;

        background-color: #ebebeb;

        padding: 5px;

        border: 1px solid #cbc9c9;

        width: 450px;

        margin: auto;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
      }

      .form__field {
        display: block;
      }
      [class*="--checkbox"] {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      [data-conditional] {
        display: none;
      }
      #flight:checked ~ [data-conditional*="flight"] {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      }
      #hotel:checked ~ [data-conditional*="hotel"] {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      }
      #transfer:checked ~ [data-conditional*="travel"] {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
      }

      input[type="text"] {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
        height: 25px;

        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
        border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
      }

      input[type="date"] {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
        height: 25px;

        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
        border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
      }

      textarea {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
        height: 25px;

        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
        border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
      }

      select {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
        height: 35px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
        border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
      }

      input[type="time"] {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 8px 10px 9px 35px;
        height: 25px;

        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
        border: solid 1px #cbc9c9;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/0px 0px 4px 4px;
        border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px/5px 5px 4px 4px;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: #4c4c4c;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      a.button {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: white;
        padding: 6px 25px 0px 20px;
        margin: 10px 8px 20px 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 50px;
        height: 27px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #3a57af;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58, 87, 175, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58, 87, 175, 0.75);
        box-shadow: 0 3px rgba(58, 87, 175, 0.75);
        transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
        top: 0px;
        position: relative;
      }

      a.button:hover {
        top: 3px;
        background-color: #2e458b;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
      }

      p {
        color: black;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="form-style-1">
      <h1>Travel Registration Form</h1>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input name="orgid" type="hidden" value="00D8E000000DW9t" />
        <input name="retURL" type="hidden" value="http://" />
        <fieldset>
          <h3>
            Select Travel
          </h3>
          <input
            class="form__input form__input--checkbox"
            data-input="00N8E000002AjRq"
            id="flight"
            type="checkbox"
          />
          <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="flight">
            <span class="form__label">Flight</span>
          </label>
          <input
            class="form__input form__input--checkbox"
            id="hotel"
            type="checkbox"
          />
          <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="hotel">
            <span class="form__label">Hotel</span>
          </label>

          <input
            class="form__input form__input--checkbox"
            id="transfer"
            type="checkbox"
          />
          <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="transfer">
            <span class="form__label">Transfer </span>
          </label>

          <!--Above is the checkboxes code -->

          <p
            class="form__field form__field--text"
            data-conditional="flight hotel travel"
          >
            <span class="form__input">Traveler's Information </span>
          </p>

          <div data-conditional="flight hotel travel">
            <label class="form__field--text" for="name"
              ><span class="form__label">Traveler Name </span
              ><input
                class="form__input"
                id="name"
                maxlength="80"
                name="name"
                size="20"
                type="text"
              />
            </label>

            <label class="form__field--text" for="email"
              >Email<input
                class="form__input"
                id="email"
                maxlength="80"
                name="email"
                size="20"
                type="text"
            /></label>

            <label class="form__field--text" for="phone"
              >Phone<input
                class="form__input"
                id="phone"
                maxlength="40"
                name="phone"
                size="20"
                type="text"
            /></label>

            <label class="form__field--text" for="subject"
              >Subject<input
                class="form__input"
                id="subject"
                maxlength="80"
                name="subject"
                size="20"
                type="text"
            /></label>

            <label class="form__field--text" for="description"
              >Description<textarea
                class="form__input"
                name="description"
              ></textarea
            ></label>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

You could now decrease the width of inputs or increase the width of `form-style-1` to achieve a more elegant design.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly then try wrapping your labels and input fields in divs and then set those to inline blocks?

HTML:

```
   <div class="form-input">
        <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel travel" for="name">
            <span class="form__label">Traveler Name</span>
            <input class="form__input" id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" /> 
        </label>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-input {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example , but when i input the div  the input fields got hide even if i do the css part

Comment: It disappears? Are you sure it disappears or is the styling just not coming through?

Comment: i thinkit is because of my checkboxes option

Comment: i tried to add below code but after the code it shows entire input fields visible without checking the checkboxes .form-input label {

display:inline-block;
float:left;
position:relative;
}

Comment: @PrihanJerad How about making use of table?